Generate string using regex in python
Given regex
"(?P\<year\>\\d{4})_(?P\<month\>\\d{2})_(?P\<day\>\\d{2})"

and dictionary
{year: 2024, month: 01, day: 01}

I want to produce string
2024_01_01
I have tried re.sub but it seems to require a dummy string where you want to replace values. Could there be a better suited alternative to this?

Why do you want to use regex for this?

That dictionary has invalid syntax. Did you mean {'year': '2024', 'month': '01', 'day': '01'}?

This question is similar to: Reversing a regular expression in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like including what research you've done. What have you looked at?

@InSync It's probably helpful, but it's not the same because that question is about producing any string from a regex specification while this one is about producing a specific string.

@wjandrea How about Python generate string based on regex format, which was also closed as a duplicate of the aforementioned question?

Folks in comments. Here is a newcomer to s.o. and a  begginner, with what is very likely a XY problem - which is what should be tackled.  Obviously there are tens of better ways of rendering the desired string from date components than the path the O.P. was pursuing.

Focusing on regex seems like an XY problem. Could this be what you're actually looking for? How do I format a string using a dictionary? TLDR fmt = '{year}_{month}_{day}'; date = {'year': '2024', 'month': '01', 'day': '01'}; fmt.format(**date) → '2024_01_01'

@jsbueno In the case of an XY problem, the OP should be asked to clarify their intent.

@jsbueno I'm not sure if you're referring to me, but regardless if it helps, I voted to close as "needs clarity" mainly because of the invalid dict syntax. It's not clear if the values are supposed to be strings or ints.

You don't need RegEx for this if you already have the proper info in a dictionary (it's likely not the right tool anyway).
Note: that dictionary is invalid as-written. For this example I've converted its keys and values into strings
# here is your dict (formatted as strings)
date_dict = {'year': '2024', 'month': '01', 'day': '01'}
# use the 'str.join' method to concatenate the dict values w/ your desired separator
date_str = '_'.join(date_dict.values())
print(date_str)
# >>> 2024_01_01


Regular expressions are a usuall solution to parse strings, and may be poorly suited to render strings back.
It should be noted that the regular f-strings (or str.format method) in Python, along with the custom text-formatting options allowed by the datetime-module can be a better choice there.
If your date is actually in a dictionary, then it can work like this:
date_dct = {"year": 2024, "month": 1, "day": 1}
message = "{year}_{month:02d}_{day:02d}".format_map(date_dct)

Or, if you get your date as a date/datetime object:
from datetime import date
date_dct = {"year": 2024, "month": 1, "day": 1}

# Parse your dict data into a proper date object:
day = date(**date_dct)

# Use the "strftime" format specification to render date using an f-string
print(f"{day:%Y_%m_%d}")

Note that in these approaches, the date information should be used as numbers, instead of strings. If they are indeed as strings and you don't want to parse the proper date, an string formatting operation can work directly as:
message = "{year}_{month}_{day}".format_map(date_dct)"
With no information needed about the number of digits for each component.
